# Python-- access relative file path from two different files from different directory in same project

Tags: python, import, path

If the question is not clear, Let me give an example. Suppose this is my project structure:

```
app.py
dir1  
   ... Workflow.py
   ... config.yml
```

In `app.py` I import `Workflow`. `Workflow.py` reads from `config.yml`. If I want to run `workflow.py` individually I can simply give the file path as `config.yml` because it is in the same folder. However, when I import `Workflow` in `app.py` and run it, the path can not be resolved. If I change the path in `workflow.py` as `dir1/config.yml`,  `app.py` runs successfully but now `workflow.py` does not run.

I want to be able to run both the file individually. How do I resolve this path issue?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you directory structure looks like:

```
rootdir
├───app.py
└───dir1
    ├───workflow.py
    └───config.yml
```

For example, `workflow.py` looks like this:

```
def run():
with open('config.yml') as c:
    print(c.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Running `python app.py` from rootdir, will produce an error due to the fact that `config.yml` is a relative path and it is **relative to your current working directory** which is `rootdir` and `rootdir/config.yml` does not exist.

Running `python workflow.py` from dir1 would succeed, because the relative path would point to an existing file in this case.

### Simple Solution

You could make the path different depending on how the script was called using the `__name__` variable:

```
CONFDIR = 'dir1'

def run():
    with open(f'{CONFDIR}/config.yml') as c:
        print(c.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CONFDIR = '.'
    run()
```

This way, the if block will get executed only if the script is run directly (`python workflow.py`) and the import from app.py will work correctly.
On the other hand, if you wanted to run `python dir1/workflow.py` from `rootdir`, it would fail, because the relative path to config is wrong again.

### Better Solution

You could create an environment variable and store the path to the file there. `workflow.py` would look like this:

```
import os

def run():
    with open(os.environ.get("CONFIG_PATH", "./config.yml")) as c:
        print(c.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Run `app.py` like this:

```
CONFIG_PATH="dir1/config.yml" python ./app.py
```

Run `workflow.py` like this:

```
CONFIG_PATH="./config.yml" python ./workflow.py
```

or like this if `CONFIG_PATH` is not set:

```
python ./workflow.py
```

This way the path to the configuration file is also configurable and you don't need to hardcode it. It also provides a default value of `./config.yml` if `CONFIG_PATH` is not set.